# MQL4 - How to get Lowest and Higher OrderOpenPrice

Tags: mql4

Please give me advice how to get Lowest and Highest price from existing open-trade position like the code below.

```
int OPLowHigh(string symbol, int dir, int mgc)
{

double HLPrice;

for(int d = 0; d <= OrdersTotal(); d++)
  {
    if(OrderSelect(d,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES) == true)
      {
        if(OrderSymbol() == symbol && OrderType() == dir && OrderMagicNumber() == mgc)
          {
            HLPrice = OrderOpenPrice ???????????

          }
      }
  }

return(HLPrice);

}
```

Thank you very much,

Noel

Answer (score 0):

There are few things wrong with the above code.

1. The returned data type should be `double`, not `int` because the
   prices are of `double` type.
2. You should not iterate to the `OrdersTotal()`. The max index
   possible is `OrdersTotal()-1` since the orders are numbered in a 0
   based way.
3. I am a little bit unclear whether both the highest and lowest
   values should be returned from the same function. If so you can
   achieve that by using `reference parameters`

However, the following is the code I wrote for getting the highest open price of the opened positions.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Returns the highest order open price among the opened orders           |
//| Return value -1: there is no position(of symbol,dir,magicNum) available|
//+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
double GetHighestOpenPrice(const string symbol, const int dir, const int magicNum)
{
   int total = OrdersTotal();
   if(total == 0) return(-1);
   double highestOpenPrice = -1;
   for(int i = total - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      if(!OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) continue;
      if(OrderCloseTime() != 0) continue;
      if(OrderMagicNumber() != magicNum) continue;
      if(OrderSymbol() != Symbol()) continue;
      if(OrderType() != dir) continue;

      // if the order open price is greater than the previously stored order open price then update it
      if(OrderOpenPrice() > highestOpenPrice)highestOpenPrice = OrderOpenPrice();
   }
   return(highestOpenPrice);
}
```